# Что делать, если в Python SQLite в таблицу функция игнорирует повторный INSERT INTO ? Помогите, пожалуйста!

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, telebot, sqlite3

В общем, пишу ТГ бота (на pyTelegramBotApi) - кликер с наградами - и подключил базу данных в отдельном файле, который вызывается после нажатия кнопки в боте. А значит, что создаётся и таблица.
В неё *записывается динамическая информация, которая изменяется в ходе пользования ботом* (кол-во открытых кейсов, кол-во приглашённых и кол-во выведенных скинов) Вот код:

```
import sqlite3 as sq

def info_table_create(bot, chat_id, user, referals, skins, cases, reg_since='(В разработке)'):
    with sq.connect('users_info.db', isolation_level=None) as conn:
        cur = conn.cursor()

        cur.execute(f"""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users_info (
            user TEXT NOT NULL,
            для_красоты TEXT NOT NULL DEFAULT '--------------------',
            reg_since TEXT NOT NULL,
            referals INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
            skins INTEGER NOT NULL,
            cases INTEGER NOT NULL
        )""")

        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users_info (user, reg_since, referals, skins, cases) VALUES ('<b>Имя:</b> {user}', '<b>Зарегестрирован с</b> {reg_since}', '<b>Приграшено людей:</b> {referals}', '<b>Скинов выведено:</b> {skins}', '<b>Кейсов открыто:</b> {cases}')")

        cur.execute("SELECT * FROM users_info")

        list = cur.fetchall()
        result = f'''
{list[0][0]} 
{list[0][1]}
{list[0][2]}
{list[0][3]}
{list[0][4]}
{list[0][5]}
'''
        print(result)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, result)
        
    conn.commit()
    cur.close()
    conn.close()
```

Дело в том, что при нажатии на кнопку должна создаться и/или вызваться таблица users_info и  в неё должны быть записаны данные, после чего распечатаны в консоли и в боте. При первом вызове всё работает корректно, при втором же, после изменения мной информации через бота, код почему-то игнорирует строку с `cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users_info (user, reg_since, referals, skins, cases) VALUES ('<b>Имя:</b> {user}', '<b>Зарегестрирован с</b> {reg_since}', '<b>Приграшено людей:</b> {referals}', '<b>Скинов выведено:</b> {skins}', '<b>Кейсов открыто:</b> {cases}')")`, то есть *не перезаписывает обновлённые данные в таблицу*, и в итоге выводится прежняя информация (ошибок в консоли нет).
Я пробовал буквально всё, что в яндексе на первых ссылках при запросе:

> "что делать если питон игнорирует insert into в бд sql"

и тому подобных.
Помогите пожалуйста, это очень важный проект для меня!

Если понадобится доп. информация - милости прошу в комментарии)

**Спасибо.**

Comment: Добавьте отладочную печать, а лучше логирование, да посмотрите. Может туда вообще управление не попадает, может переменные те же самые приходят, да что угодно может быть. Такое только отладкой проверяется. Тем более если важный проект, то учитесь делать логирование. А так то не очень понятно, зачем вы в базу пишете `html` теги, обычно в базу пишут только данные, а теги нужно навешивать когда из базы прочитаете данные и будете выводить куда-то. В базе лишняя ерунда ни к чему.

Comment: @CrazyElf 
Насколько я понимаю, отладку я сделал - вон, ```print(result)``` перед ```bot.send_message(chat_id, result)```. И информация печатается, т.е. INSERT INTO реально игнорируется.
А что касается тегов, то я при импортировании модуля telebot указал ```parse_mode='html'```, так что в телеграме этот текст будет уже с жирным шрифтом.

Я начинающий программист, так что без обид, если чего-то не понял из комментария)

Comment: А, стоп, так вы же делаете `SELECT *`, потом `fetchall` и сами же берёте из списка только первую запись (с индексом `0`). Записи в базу добавляются, но вы их сами в `result` не помещаете, а выбираете только первую запись и её печатаете. Кстати, `list` плохое название для переменной, не нужно перекрывать встроенные типы питона. `list[0][0]` - это первое поле первой из полученных записей и т.д.

Comment: @CrazyElf Да, я, видимо, не внёс конкретики. Но я пишу ```list[0][0]```, потому что в ```list``` сохраняется только один кортеж. А в кортеже несколько переменных

Comment: @CrazyElf Я мог бы дописать строку, чтобы при создании таблицы предыдущая удалялась, и тогда это будет работать. Но возникнет другая проблема: при перезапуске бота (основного файла с кодом) все нужные данные будут удалены :(
А по поводу названия словаря - спасибо, приму совет

Comment: Так вы что хотите то, я так и не понял. Записи в базу добавляются. И вы их все из базы выбираете. Но потом из этой выборки берёте только самую первую запись и её объявляете результатом. Это вас не устраивает, ок, а какой бы результат вас устроил? Выборка последней записи? Ну возьмите для начала не [0], а [-1] и будет вам последняя запись, а не первая.

Comment: @CrazyElf Меня не устраивает то, что запись не обновляется при повторном вызове этой функции, хотя строка ```cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO users_info (user, reg_since, referals, skins, cases) VALUES ('<b>Имя:</b> {user}', '<b>Зарегестрирован с</b> {reg_since}', '<b>Приграшено людей:</b> {referals}', '<b>Скинов выведено:</b> {skins}', '<b>Кейсов открыто:</b> {cases}')")

``` имеется. Запись при первом вызове добавляется, а при втором не обновляется